# Correct if statement with multiple variables

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-10, odoo-9

```
  if not self.group_id.id and self.part_id.id and self.taks_template_id.id and self.project_id.allow_parts:
                raise ValidationError(_("Project must have Group Part and Template fields selecte"))
```

all 3 fields must be selected. group_id part_id taks_template_id , and allow_parts must be true. if allow_parts is True and 1 or all 3 fields empty then we get an error message. if it's false then those 3 fields can be empty. how do I write correct IF statement?

Comment: I really don't understand the logic. Can you create a simpler example without all the complex variables and all? and inputs & what to expect

Comment: Please describe your problem properly.